# For which values of $ \alpha$, $e^x+ \alpha \cdot x^3$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to say for which values of $ \alpha$ the following function is convex in  $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ e^x+ \alpha \cdot x^3.$$

Applying the definition, the function is convex if
$$ e^{ \lambda x_1+ (1- \lambda) x_2} + \alpha ( \lambda x_1+ (1- \lambda) x_2) \le \lambda (e^{x_1+ \alpha (x_1)^3} ) + (1- \lambda)(x_2+ \alpha (x_2)^3)   \\\Rightarrow \alpha  \le \frac{\lambda e^{ \lambda x_1}+ (1- \lambda)e^{ \lambda x_2} - e^{ \lambda x_1+ (1- \lambda) x_2}}{\lambda x_1+ (1- \lambda) x_2-\lambda (x_1)^3+ (1- \lambda) (x_2)^3}.$$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It might be easier to check for which values of $\alpha$ the second derivative of $f$ is non-negative.

Comment: A twice-differentiable function of a single variable is convex if and only if its second derivative is nonnegative on its entire domain.

Comment: $6 \alpha x > - e^x$ and then $\alpha > - \frac{e^x}{6x }$ if x>0 and $\alpha < - \frac{e^x}{6x }$ if x<0 .  I've studied the function and found that $- \frac{e}{6} < \alpha < 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = e^x + \alpha x^2$ is convex in $\Bbb R$ exactly if
$$
g(x) = f''(x) = e^x +6 \alpha x
$$
is non-negative for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

If $\alpha > 0$ then $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty$, so $f$ is not convex in that case.

If $\alpha = 0$ then $g(x) = e^x > 0$, i.e. $f$ is convex.

If $\alpha < 0$ then $g$ has a unique minimum where $g'(x_0) = 0$, that is at $x_0 = \ln(-6\alpha)$. The minimal value of $g$ is
$$
 g(x_0) = -6\alpha + 6 \alpha \ln(-6\alpha) = -6\alpha(1-\ln(-6\alpha)) 
$$
and that is non-negative if $\ln(-6\alpha) \le 1$ or $\alpha \ge -e/6$.

Combining these results we see that $f$ is convex if $-e/6 \le \alpha \le 0$.